# how to force divs to span 100% of the available height and width

Tags: html, css

I have the following template:

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:#ccc;">
        Data
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:#ccc;width:80px;">
        <span>Work: 22</span>
        <span>Todos: 33</span>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

But the first nested `div` does not span all the height available to it. So that both the divs match in height.

Also, I want to force text Data to be at top left.

[image]

How to do the same?

Comment: parent div {display: flex} + remove display: inline-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.warp{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="warp">
    <div style="background-color:#ccc;">
        Data
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#ccc;width:80px;">
        <span>Work: 22</span>
        <span>Todos: 33</span>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

**if you want space btween those divs:**
use `margin-right`

```css
    .warp{
        display: flex;
    }
    .data{
        margin-right: 7px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="warp">
        <div style="background-color:#ccc;" class="data">
            Data
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#ccc;width:80px;">
            <span>Work: 22</span>
            <span>Todos: 33</span>  
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 1):

just make `display: flex` to parent `div`

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:#ccc;">
            Data
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:#ccc;width:80px;">
            <span>Work: 22</span>
            <span>Todos: 33</span>  
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you still want the space between the two divs:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.data {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 40px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.input {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 80px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="data">
    Data
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <span>Work: 22</span>
    <span>Todos: 33</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the change you need to do:

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="background-color:#ccc;width:40px;">
    Data
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:#ccc;width:80px;">
    <span>Work: 22</span>
    <span>Todos: 33</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I took the liberty to make a working snippet with your code and change `u` to `you`.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to fix the height, or use flex - tables can help you with that

```
<div style="display: table; ">
    <div style="display:table-cell;background-color:#ccc; vertical-align: middle;">
        Data
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;background-color:#ccc;width:80px; vertical-align: middle;">
        <span>Work: 22</span>
        <span>Todos: 33</span>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: And why not, in that case, use a real `<table>`?

Comment: Inline `style="display: table;"` in a div, cleaner code? For real? :)

Comment: @JeremyThille i just edited the code from question, of course you would remove inline style and put it in css file, but structure was not the question here so i just gave an answer from what i had

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this Code:

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
}
.parent .child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background: #ccc;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}
.parent .child span { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            Data
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <span>Work: 22</span>
            <span>Todos: 33</span>  
        </div>  
    </div>
```